# Center an item with position: relative

Tags: css, alignment, css-position, center

I've got a menu that appears on hover over an absolutely positioned div. All of the menu items have to be relatively positioned because the absolutely div will appear multiple times on a page and will appear in multiple sizes in one instance.

How would I center multiple items with `position: relative` both vertically and horizontally when I won't know the the size of the parent div?

I know the `position: absolute` trick with negative margins, but this situation calls for something different.

Here's the code:

```
.OuterCase { 
  position  : absolute; 
  width     : 100%;  
  height    : 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

.InnerItem  { 
   width  : 38px;
   height : 38px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I've got it to center the items horizontally; it's getting the vertical that's being a bit elusive.

Comment: Your codez will be HUGELY appreciated, as answering your question without them is a little hard. :)

Comment: You should add your solution as a separate answer, and accept that answer so everybody knows this question is answered.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you DO need to position: relative.

Comment: When position is set (relative, absolute, etc.), "margin: 0 auto" doesn't seem to work.  The important trick here is "text-align:center".  It solved my problem.  Thank you so much!

Comment: do this using right : 50%

Answer (score 151):

Much simpler:

```
position: relative; 
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

You are now centered in your parent element. You can do that vertically too.

Comment: This won't work if the element is not the first child (not absolutely positioned first child).

Comment: (this is on the inner div)

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, you may also use the [CSS3 Flexible Box Model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/).
It's a great way to create flexible layouts that can also be applied to center content like so:

```
#parent {
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    display:-webkit-box;
}
```

Comment: Mozilla has its own prefix, -moz. There is also a new Flexbox, see http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Answer (score 24):

If you have a relatively- (or otherwise-) positioned div you can center something inside it with `margin:auto`

[Vertical centering](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) is a bit tricker, but possible.

Comment: Best answer if positioning horizontally

Answer (score 17):

You can use `calc` to position element relative to center. For example if you want to position element `200px` right from the center .. you can do this :

```
#your_element{
    position:absolute;
    left: calc(50% + 200px);
}
```

#### Dont forget this

When you use signs `+` and `-` you must have one blank space between sign and number, but when you use signs `*` and `/` there is no need for blank space.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed for my project, thanks

Comment: Its not accurate, but nice solution. The better result would be if you know 
 element width and height, for instance w: 40, h: 30, then left: calc(50% - 20px), right: calc(50% - 15px). that would center element accurately

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create an extra wrapper to center the element vertically.

```css
#container{
  border:solid 1px #33aaff;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

#helper{
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  top:50%;
  border:dotted 1px #ff55aa;
}

#centered{
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  top:-50%;
  border:solid 1px #ff55aa;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="helper">
    <div id="centered"></div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Just make sure the height of the parent is greater than the height of the child.

Answer (score 0):

An other simple solution I did not yet see here:

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 40vw;
}

.child{
    margin:auto;
}
```