# CSS position relative div not responsive

Tags: html, css, bulma

Hello i have a background which i want to add div over it like this picture
im using bulma css framework
[image]
i was able to achive this look by writing this code

index.html

```
    <div class="section newsletter">
    <figure class="image">
        <img src="src/img/newsletter.png">
    </figure>
            <div class="form">
                <h5>Keep updated with out latest news.<br>Subscribe to our newsletter</h5>
                <div class="field has-addons">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="control">
                        <a type="button" class="button btn-grad is-dark">
                            Subscribe
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.newsletter{
padding:0px;
.form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;        
    width:588px;
    height:297px;
    background: $bg-transperant;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 16px;
    // Layout
    position: relative;
    left: 140px;
    top: -386px;
    h5{
        padding: 50px 60px 40px 60px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 46px;
        color: #2F4B6E;
    }
    div{
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .input{
        height: 50px;
        width: 352px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
        border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    }
}
```

}

the problem is that itsn't responsive in mobile or tablet
it looks like this [image]

im using position relative to able to put the div on the top of the image
how can i do it better for example to make it responsive ?
also there is a large white space below the picture i don't know why

Live Project Repo https://github.com/Ov3rControl/ReachGate
Live Overview: https://ov3rcontrol.github.io/ReachGate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be 3 problems combined.

1) Ensure that you have [your viewport set to responsive in the head](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

2) Don't use hard-coded dimensions for containers that expand beyond the smallest possible viewport. Notice your form is set to a 588px width. Try doing `width: auto;` and then `max-width: 588px;` instead.

3) Consider not hard-coding your positioning. Try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626314/css-center-item-with-positionrelative) instead to center relatively positioned containers.

Looking really pretty though, good job! One aside: It's considered good practice to always tie a label to an input for accessibility purposes. If you don't want it visible that's fine! [See this](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)

---

I did the following to responsively center the form:

```html
<!------------------------------------[NewsLetter Section - START]------------------------------------------->
    <div class="section newsletter">
        <div class="form">
            <h5>Keep updated with our latest news.<br>Subscribe to our newsletter</h5>
            <div class="field has-addons">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                </div>

                <div class="control">
                    <a type="button" class="button btn-grad is-dark">
                        Subscribe
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!------------------------------------[NewsLetter Section - END]------------------------------------------->
```

```
.newsletter {
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url('src/img/newsletter.png');
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  .form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 270px;
    max-width: 320px;
    background: $bg-transperant;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 16px;

    // Layout
    h5 {
      padding: 50px 60px 40px 60px;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 25px;
      line-height: 46px;
      color: #2f4b6e;
    }

    div {
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .input {
      height: auto;
      height: 50px;
      width: 352px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
      border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer i tried but with no luck 
now i tried to give the div a background image and put a another div inside it 
and give it margins or something but faild as well :))

Comment: Can you somehow provide the context of the whole page? There must be something else higher up affecting things.

Comment: Edited my response! Just be careful about developing a few bad habits!

You have a form here which should be using the `form` element that you can submit with a `button` with `type="submit"`. Instead, you're using a div with an anchor tag to submit.

Good luck!

Comment: hello i just tried your code copy & paste and it look like this broken in desktop tablet and mobile :( http://oi65.tinypic.com/2yl9v8i.jpg

Comment: Sorry to see that. I didn't notice any issues on Chrome latest at any viewport. Are you using any sort of autoprefixing to manage CSS prefixes for other browsers?